# jQuery Form Validation - Can't Submit After preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm just starting to learn jQuery and attempting to create my own form validation as a method of learning.

What I'm trying to achieve is so that when the form is submitted it will check if any of the fields with the class *.required* are empty and if so highlight the field. This works fine, however when the form is properly filled out it won't submit.

I really can't see where I'm going wrong. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

```
$('#contact').submit(function(event) { 

  event.preventDefault();
  var isFormValid = true;

  $('.required').each(function() {    

    if ($(this).val() == '') { 

       $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass('invalid');
       isFormValid = false;
    }

  });

  if(isFormValid = true) { 
     $('#contact').submit(); 
  }


});
```

Comment: check the value `console.log(isFormValid)`

Comment: You are trying to submit the form *recursively*. The same handler gets hit again.

Comment: TrueBlueAussie answers your question correctly but just as a heads up, you also have an error in your if statement. isFormValid = true will always return true because you're reassigning the value. Use === (or == when you have a reason) to do a conditional check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to submit the form recursively. The same handler gets hit again when you call `.submit()` (which prevents the actual submit).

You are also assigning the flag in your `if`. `if(isFormValid = true)` should have used `==`, but that code is not needed anyway.

Move the `preventDefault` to where it actually fails *only* and do not try to re`submit`. Just let it fall through.

```
$('#contact').submit(function(event) { 
  $('.required').each(function() {    
    if ($(this).val() == '') { 
       $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass('invalid');

       // only prevent submit if there is a problem
       event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The isFormValid flag is redundant in your example code.

Comment: @Pieter Beulque: also true. Corrected as well now.

Comment: That's great thank you, also helped me understand where I was going wrong

Answer (score 1):

i think the first $('#contact').submit(function(event){...}) overrides the $('#contact').submit() which can possibly cause recursion. so try doing this instead

```javascript
// when user clicks submit
$('#contact').submit(function(event) { 

  // iterates through the inputs with the class 'required'
  $('.required').each(function() {    

    /**
     * we make assumption that it is a valid input.
     * because if a user probably makes a mistake in like more than one of the input 
     * but corrects one of it successfully without knowing 
     * the last other one was still wrong, it will make sense just marking that single field
     * invalid.
     **/
    $(this).addClass('valid');

    if ($(this).val() == '') { 

       // only prevents default when user input is invalid
       event.preventDefault();

       // shows which field is invalid
       $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass('invalid');

    }

  });

});
```

Comment: the event.preventDefault() is only called if the contact button is clicked and not on submit. so calling the .submit() function do no prevent default action in this case. corrected the comparison issue

Comment: With this solution you still have the problem of submission via keypress (e.g. Enter) and not just click. It will allow invalid submission.

Comment: Better... I'm now just left with a overwhelming sense of déjà vu :)

Answer (score 0):

if(isFormValid = true) {   should be if(isFormValide) {

Comment: Cleaner, but makes no difference as the real problem is the recursion and always using `preventDefault`